# displaying Hexadecimal value in LCD

Tags: atmega, avr-gcc, lcd

I wrote LCD interface program for Atmega328 (Though there are libraries available, I wanted to write from scratch). But have two problems.
1. Sometimes LCD does not display correctly. Only few strips are seen. I end up in resetting once or twice.
2. I am unable to display hexadecimal values usingdisplayOneByteHexValue(). However ASCII coversion was correct and I could see that in Atmel Simulator. Below is the code. I am using Atmel Studio 6.2

```
/*
* EmbeddedProgram1.c
*
* Created: 16-05-2015 08:19:38
*  Author: Mahesha
*/


#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#endif

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Only Change following when changing pin numbers.
// All Data bits have to be assigned sequentially in same the port . RS and EN must be allocated in the same port
#define LCDPORT PORTD
#define LCDDDR DDRD
// used pins on port appropriate ports
#define LCD_DB4 2    // PORTD.2
#define LCD_DB5 3    // PORTD.3
#define LCD_DB6 4    // PORTD.4
#define LCD_DB7 5    // PORTD.5
#define LCD_ENABLE_BIT  6     // PORTD.6 Enable
#define LCD_RS 7     // PORTD.7 Register Select
//#define LCD_RW     // R/W is connected to GND permanently


#define LCD_DATA_BITS_MASK 0x3C
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#define SET_EIGHT_BIT_MODE() LCDPORT|=((1<<LCD_DB5)|(1<<LCD_DB4))    // Set DB4 and DB5 as 1 for setting eight bit mode.
#define SET_FOUR_BIT_MODE() LCDPORT|=(1<<LCD_DB5)
#define SET_INSTRUCTION_MODE() LCDPORT&=~(1<<LCD_RS)      //Function to select command port on LCD RS pin bit 2
#define SET_DATA_MODE() LCDPORT|=(1<<LCD_RS)         //Function to select data port on LCD
#define DISABLE_LCD() LCDPORT&=~(1<<LCD_ENABLE_BIT)           //Function to disable LCD P0.18
#define ENABLE_LCD() LCDPORT|=(1<<LCD_ENABLE_BIT)            //Function to Enable LCD     P0.18

//#define EIGHT_BIT_MODE 0x30                                      // 0 0 1 1 x x x x DB7 to DB0 0f LCD
#define BUSY_FLAG_WAIT_TIME 20
#define FOUR_BIT_5_BY_10_2LINE 0x28
#define LCD_INIT_DELAY 100      // Give a delay of 200 msec after reset. // Datasheet says 10 msec delay.


//Commands Finalized
#define CLEAR_DISPLAY 0x01
#define CURSOR_HOME 0x02    // return home
#define ENTRY_MODE_LEFT_TO_RIGHT 0x06              // Cursor direction from Left to right   , Bit 1 of entry mode in LCD
#define DISPLAY_OFF  0x08        // Blink ON, Cursor ON etc are don't care
#define CURSOR_OFF_BLINK_OFF   0x0C
#define CURSOR_OFF_BLINK_ON 0x0D    // blink on Even 0x0D also works. So cursor need not be ON
#define CURSOR_ON_BLINK_OFF 0x0E    // blink off
#define CURSOR_ON_BLINK_ON 0x0F
#define SHIFT_ENTIRE_LEFT 0x18
#define SHIFT_CURSOR_LEFT 0x10
#define SHIFT_ENTIRE_RIGHT 0x1C
#define SHIFT_CURSOR_RIGHT 0x14

// Function prototypes
void unpackAndSend(char  data);
void waitForBusyFlagToClear(void);
void sendLCDPulse(void);
void displayInRow1(char* data);
void displayInRow2(char* data);
void displayInRow1WithPosition(char* data, uint8_t position);
void displayInRow2WithPosition(char* data, uint8_t position);
void sendTextToLCD(char *data);
void displayOneByteHexValue(unsigned char,unsigned char,char);
void initializeLCD(void);

void CL_delayMS(unsigned int delayMS)
{
    while(delayMS--)
    {
        _delay_ms(1);
    }
}

void CL_delayuS(unsigned int delayus)
{
    while(delayus--)
    {
        _delay_us(1);
    }
}


// writes a char to the LCD
void writeCharToLCD(unsigned char data)
{
    SET_DATA_MODE();                  // RS bit has to be 1 for data mode
    unpackAndSend(data);

}

// sendLCD pulse will just enable and disable the EN bit of LCD display.
void sendLCDPulse(void)
{
    DISABLE_LCD();
    CL_delayuS(50);
    ENABLE_LCD();
    CL_delayMS(1);
    DISABLE_LCD();
    CL_delayMS(1);
}

// writes an instruction to the LCD
void sendLCDCommand(unsigned char inst)
{
    SET_INSTRUCTION_MODE();
    unpackAndSend(inst);
    waitForBusyFlagToClear();

}

// Unpack and send data will separate two nibbles and send twice.
void unpackAndSend(char inst)
{
    char temp=inst;
    DISABLE_LCD();
    // SET_WRITE_MODE();               // If write is permanently disabled, do not use this.

    LCDPORT &= (~LCD_DATA_BITS_MASK);   // Clear the data bits
    //sendLCDPulse();
    inst&=0xF0;
    inst=inst>>4;                            // Get the upper nibble
    LCDPORT|=inst<<LCD_DB4;                 //Replace the bits starting from position of bit LCD_DB4 with this new data
    sendLCDPulse();
    LCDPORT &= (~LCD_DATA_BITS_MASK);  // Clear the data bits again
    //sendLCDPulse();
    temp &=0x0f; //send low nibble
    LCDPORT|=temp<<LCD_DB4;
    sendLCDPulse();

}

// waitForBusyFlagToClear functio can wait for the busy bit, But since we are permanently connected R/W pin to ground, we cannot read
// the flag from LCD. In case busy bit has to be read, implementation has to be changed.

void waitForBusyFlagToClear(void)
{
    CL_delayMS(BUSY_FLAG_WAIT_TIME);
}


// clear display
void clearDisplay(void)
{
    sendLCDCommand (CLEAR_DISPLAY);
}

// return home
void returnCursorHome(void)
{
    sendLCDCommand (CURSOR_HOME);
}

// LCD off
void displayOFF(void)
{
    sendLCDCommand (DISPLAY_OFF);
}

// LCD on
void displayONCursorOFF(void)
{
    sendLCDCommand (CURSOR_OFF_BLINK_OFF);
}

// cursor on
void displayONCursorON(void)
{
    sendLCDCommand (CURSOR_ON_BLINK_OFF);
}

// blink on
void cursorOffBlinkOn(void)
{
    sendLCDCommand (CURSOR_OFF_BLINK_ON);
}

// blink OFF, but display and cursors are ON
void cursorOnBlinkOff(void)
{
    sendLCDCommand (CURSOR_ON_BLINK_OFF);
}

// All are ON
void cursorOnBlinkOn(void)
{
    sendLCDCommand (CURSOR_ON_BLINK_ON);
}

//go to first line
void LCDline1 (void)

{
    sendLCDCommand (0b10000000);
}

//go to second line
void LCDline2 (void)

{
    sendLCDCommand (0b11000000);
}


// goto position x,y
// row1 or row2 are the parameters
// So parameters can be 1 or 2
void setRowAndColumnPositionOnDisplay (unsigned char rowNumber, unsigned char position)
{
    unsigned char pos;

    if (rowNumber == 1)
    {
        pos = 0x00 + position;
        pos|=0x80;                  // Command to set 1st Row.
    }

    else //if (rowNumber == 1)     // Either row 1 or two. We cannot have else option.
    {
        pos = 0x40 + position;
        pos|=0xC0;                // Command to set second row.
    }
    sendLCDCommand (pos);
}

void displayInRow1(char* data)
{
    sendLCDCommand(0x80);        // Set DDRAM Address as 0
    sendTextToLCD(data);
}

void displayInRow1WithPosition(char* data, unsigned char position)
{
    // The position cannot be more than 15. Display is 16 characters (0-15).
    if(position>15)
    {
        position = 15;
    }
    sendLCDCommand(0x80|position);    // Change the DDRAM address to first line by
    //  keeping D7 high and setting address to 0 onwards
    sendTextToLCD(data);
}

//////////////////////////////    diaplayInRow2   /////////////////////////////////////////////

void displayInRow2(char* data)
{
    sendLCDCommand(0xC0);     // Change the DDRAM address to next line 0x40 to 4F
    sendTextToLCD(data);
}

//////////////////////    diaplayInRow2WithPosition   //////////////////////

void displayInRow2WithPosition(char* data, unsigned char position)
{
    // The position cannot be more than 15. Display is 16 characters (0-15).
    if(position>15)
    {
        position = 15;
    }
    sendLCDCommand(0xC0|position);    // Change the DDRAM address to second line by
    //keeping Bit D7 high and setting address at 0x40 onwards
    sendTextToLCD(data);
}

void scrollLcd(char *row1Data,char *row2Data)
{

    while(1)
    {
        sendLCDCommand(SHIFT_CURSOR_LEFT);
        sendLCDCommand(SHIFT_ENTIRE_LEFT);
        CL_delayMS(200);
    }
}


//write text to the LCD
void sendTextToLCD(char *data)
{
    while (*data)
    {
        writeCharToLCD(*data);
        data++;
    }
}

// Function to convert lower nibble to ASCII Value
//Only lower nibble of the input is considered and higher nibble is lost

char convertLowerNibbleToASCIIValue(char data)
{
    data&=0x0F;
    if(data<=9)
    {
        return(data+0x30);
    }
    else            // There is no chance for getting more than 0x0F in the lowerNibble Parameter)
    {
        return(data+0x37);
    }
}

// Function to convert Higher nibble to ASCII Value
//Only higher nibble of the input is considered and lower nibble is lost
char convertHigherNibbleToASCIIValue(char data)
{
    data>>=4;
    if(data<=9)
    {
        return(data+0x30);
    }
    else            // There is no chance for getting more than 0x0F in the lowerNibble Parameter)
    {
        return(data+0x37);
    }
}

void displayOneByteHexValue(unsigned char rowNum, unsigned char pos, char data)
{
    char temp;
    setRowAndColumnPositionOnDisplay(rowNum,pos);
    temp = convertHigherNibbleToASCIIValue(data);
    sendTextToLCD(&temp);
    temp = convertLowerNibbleToASCIIValue(data);
    sendTextToLCD(&temp);

}

// init LCD

void initializeLCD(void)
{
    // Set the direction of port pins connected to LCD display as output ports.
    // We are permanently connecting R/W pin to ground. So there is no read instruction in this case..
    LCDDDR |= (1<<LCD_DB4)|(1<<LCD_DB5)|(1<<LCD_DB6)|(1<<LCD_DB7)|(1<<LCD_RS)|(1<<LCD_ENABLE_BIT);

    //After reset, data sheet suggests some delay.
    CL_delayMS(LCD_INIT_DELAY);

    // Note some sites says three times 8 bit mode setting commands need to be sent.
    // But it is observed that even without this, LCD works fine. So 1st Command, 2nd Command and 3rd Commands can be deleted below.
    //ENABLE_LCD();
    // 1st Command
    SET_EIGHT_BIT_MODE();
    //sendLCDPulse();    // Do not delete this. Need to further analyse. If pulse if sent it is not working
    //CL_delayMS(5);     // Do not use this delay since delay is not acurate, Either use _delay_ms or use timers
    _delay_ms(5);

    // Second Command
    SET_EIGHT_BIT_MODE();
    //sendLCDPulse();
    _delay_us(100);
    //CL_delayuS(100);   // Do not use this delay since delay is not acurate, Either use _delay_ms or use timers

    // third Command
    SET_EIGHT_BIT_MODE();
    //sendLCDPulse();
    //CL_delayuS(100);   // Do not use this delay since delay is not acurate, Either use _delay_ms or use timers
    _delay_us(37);
    // Finally Set four bit mode
    SET_FOUR_BIT_MODE();
    //sendLCDPulse();
    CL_delayuS(100);

    // First time when 4 bit mode command is sent, only one higher nibble was sent since
    // only 4 bits are connected from MPU to LCD. Since D0 to D3 of LCD are not connected,
    // their values depend on how the pins are connected in LCD module (May be grounded, may kept open etc)
    //So again send function set command to set 2 line display mode mode and 5x7 character mode. But now two write operations to LCD is made
    // inside the function sendLCDCommand.
    sendLCDCommand (FOUR_BIT_5_BY_10_2LINE);

    //turn on display and cursor OFF, Blink OFF (sent two times using below command)
    sendLCDCommand (CURSOR_OFF_BLINK_OFF);

    //clr display
    sendLCDCommand (CLEAR_DISPLAY);

    // Set Entry mode left to right
    sendLCDCommand (ENTRY_MODE_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
}



void LCDProgramCallFromMain(char *row1Data, char *row2Data)
{
    initializeLCD();
    setRowAndColumnPositionOnDisplay (1,0);
    sendTextToLCD (row1Data);   
    displayOneByteHexValue(2,0,0xF4);

    //setRowAndColumnPositionOnDisplay (2,5);
    //displayInRow1(row1Data);
}


int main(void)
{
    LCDProgramCallFromMain("Hello", "Welcome to cloude");
    while(1)
    {


    }
}
```

Below is the image of the display I am getting. Not able to makeout where the problem is.
[image: Result]

Comment: SO is probably not the best place for this, what about migrating your question to [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: No problem. It can be migrated

Comment: Think that in the function `displayOneByteHexValue` you are using `&temp` as a 0 terminated string, but is not a 0 terminated string. This might be a problem because the function 'sendTextToLCD` reads the memory starting from `&temp` till a 0 value is encountered, so writing all bytes it reads!

Comment: In the function `displayOneByteHexValue()` try to use something like this: `char temp[2]`; then you have to initialize `temp[1]` as 0 and to set `temp[0]` as you set temp. Then call `sendTextToLCD(temp)` instead of `sendTextToLCD(&temp)` –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it worked after I changed the function as below. Thanks for the help.

```
void displayOneByteHexValue(unsigned char rowNum, unsigned char pos, char data)
{
    char temp;
    setRowAndColumnPositionOnDisplay(rowNum,pos);
    temp = convertHigherNibbleToASCIIValue(data);
    writeCharToLCD(temp);
    temp = convertLowerNibbleToASCIIValue(data);
    writeCharToLCD(temp);

}
```

I further optimized the code and below is the complete working code with small demo function called from main.

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#endif

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <avr/sfr_defs.h>


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Only Change following when changing pin numbers.
// All Data bits have to be assigned sequentially in same the port . RS and EN must be allocated in the same port
#define LCDPORT PORTD
#define LCDDDR DDRD
// used pins on port appropriate ports
#define LCD_DB4 2    // PORTD.2
#define LCD_DB5 3    // PORTD.3
#define LCD_DB6 4    // PORTD.4
#define LCD_DB7 5    // PORTD.5
#define LCD_ENABLE_BIT  6     // PORTD.6 Enable
#define LCD_RS 7     // PORTD.7 Register Select
//#define LCD_RW     // R/W is connected to GND permanently


#define LCD_DATA_BITS_MASK ((1<<LCD_DB4)|(1<<LCD_DB5)|(1<<LCD_DB6)|(1<<LCD_DB7))
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/*
#define SET_EIGHT_BIT_MODE() LCDPORT|=((1<<LCD_DB5)|(1<<LCD_DB4))    // Set DB4 and DB5 as 1 for setting eight bit mode.
#define SET_FOUR_BIT_MODE() LCDPORT|=(1<<LCD_DB5)
*/

#define SET_INSTRUCTION_MODE() LCDPORT&=~(1<<LCD_RS)      //Function to select command port on LCD RS pin bit 2
#define SET_DATA_MODE() LCDPORT|=(1<<LCD_RS)         //Function to select data port on LCD
#define DISABLE_LCD() LCDPORT&=~(1<<LCD_ENABLE_BIT)           //Function to disable LCD P0.18
#define ENABLE_LCD() LCDPORT|=(1<<LCD_ENABLE_BIT)            //Function to Enable LCD     P0.18
#define BUSY_FLAG_WAIT_TIME 20
#define FOUR_BIT_5_BY_10_2LINE 0x28
#define LCD_INIT_DELAY 100      // Give a delay of 100 msec after reset. // Datasheet says 10 msec delay.


// Function prototypes for external use (to be kept in Header file)
void sendLCDCommand(unsigned char cmd);
void displayInRow1(unsigned char* data);
void displayInRow2(unsigned char* data);
void displayInRow1WithPosition(unsigned char* data, uint8_t position);
void displayInRow2WithPosition(unsigned char* data, uint8_t position);
void sendTextToLCD(unsigned char *data);
void initializeLCD(void);


// Function prototypes for file use (only internal)
void unpackAndSend(char  data);
void waitForBusyFlagToClear(void);
void sendLCDPulse(void);
void displayOneByteHexValue(unsigned char,unsigned char,char);   // This function is no longer needed. Only for demo purpose.

// #define commands are  replaced by enums to demonstrate the feature of enumerated data types

enum DISPLAY_PROPERTY
{
CLEAR_DISPLAY=0x01,
CURSOR_HOME =  0x02,    // return home
ENTRY_MODE_LEFT_TO_RIGHT= 0x06,              // Cursor direction from Left to right , Bit 1 of entry mode in LCD
DISPLAY_OFF=  0x08,        // Blink ON, Cursor ON etc are don't care
CURSOR_OFF_BLINK_OFF= 0x0C,
CURSOR_OFF_BLINK_ON= 0x0D,    // blink on Even 0x0D also works. So cursor need not be ON
CURSOR_ON_BLINK_OFF=0x0E,    // blink off
CURSOR_ON_BLINK_ON=0x0F,
SHIFT_ENTIRE_LEFT= 0x18,
SHIFT_CURSOR_LEFT= 0x10,
SHIFT_ENTIRE_RIGHT= 0x1C,
SHIFT_CURSOR_RIGHT= 0x14,
};


void SET_EIGHT_BIT_MODE(void)
{
LCDPORT=(LCDPORT&(~LCD_DATA_BITS_MASK))|((0<<LCD_DB7)|(0<<LCD_DB6)|(1<<LCD_DB5)|(1<<LCD_DB4));    // Set DB4 and DB5 as 1 for setting eight bit mode.
}

void SET_FOUR_BIT_MODE(void)
{
LCDPORT= (LCDPORT&(~LCD_DATA_BITS_MASK)) | ((0<<LCD_DB7)|(0<<LCD_DB6)|(1<<LCD_DB5)|(0<<LCD_DB4));
}


void CL_delayMS(unsigned int delayMS)
{
    while(delayMS--)
    {
        _delay_ms(1);
    }
}

void CL_delayuS(unsigned int delayus)
{
    while(delayus--)
    {
        _delay_us(1);
    }
}


// writes a char to the LCD
void writeCharToLCD(unsigned char data)
{
SET_DATA_MODE();                  // RS bit has to be 1 for data mode
unpackAndSend(data);
}

// sendLCD pulse will just enable and disable the EN bit of LCD display.
void sendLCDPulse(void)
{
//DISABLE_LCD();
//CL_delayuS(50);
ENABLE_LCD();
CL_delayMS(1);
DISABLE_LCD();
CL_delayMS(1);
}

// writes an instruction to the LCD
void sendLCDCommand(unsigned char cmd)
{
SET_INSTRUCTION_MODE();
unpackAndSend(cmd);
waitForBusyFlagToClear();

}

// Unpack and send data will separate two nibbles and send twice.
void unpackAndSend(char inst)
{
char temp=inst;
DISABLE_LCD();
// SET_WRITE_MODE();               // If write is permanently disabled, do not use this.

LCDPORT &= (~LCD_DATA_BITS_MASK);   // Clear the data bits
//sendLCDPulse();
inst&=0xF0;
inst=inst>>4;                            // Get the upper nibble
LCDPORT|=inst<<LCD_DB4;                 //Replace the bits starting from position of bit LCD_DB4 with this new data
sendLCDPulse();
LCDPORT &= (~LCD_DATA_BITS_MASK);  // Clear the data bits again
//sendLCDPulse();
temp &=0x0f; //send low nibble
LCDPORT|=temp<<LCD_DB4;
sendLCDPulse();
}

// waitForBusyFlagToClear function can wait for the busy bit, But since we are permanently connected R/W pin to ground, we cannot read
// the flag from LCD. In case busy bit has to be read, implementation has to be changed.

void waitForBusyFlagToClear(void)
{
CL_delayMS(BUSY_FLAG_WAIT_TIME);
}


// goto position x,y
// row1 or row2 are the parameters
// So parameters can be 0 or 1
void setRowAndColumnPositionOnDisplay (unsigned char rowNumber, unsigned char position)
{
unsigned char pos;

if (rowNumber==0)            // If Row is 0, display in 1st row
{
pos = 0x00 + position;
pos|=0x80;                  // Command to set 1st Row.
}

else //if (rowNumber == 1)     // Either row 1 or two etc
{
pos = 0x40 + position;
pos|=0xC0;                // Command to set second row.
}

sendLCDCommand (pos);

}

void displayInRow1(unsigned char* data)
{
sendLCDCommand(0x80);        // Set DDRAM Address as 0
sendTextToLCD(data);
}

void displayInRow1WithPosition(unsigned char* data, unsigned char position)
{
sendLCDCommand(0x80|position);    // Change the DDRAM address to first line by
//  keeping D7 high and setting address to 0 onwards
sendTextToLCD(data);
}

//////////////////////////////    diaplayInRow2   /////////////////////////////////////////////

void displayInRow2(unsigned char* data)
{
sendLCDCommand(0xC0);     // Change the DDRAM address to next line 0x40 to 4F
sendTextToLCD(data);
}

//////////////////////    diaplayInRow2WithPosition   //////////////////////

void displayInRow2WithPosition(unsigned char* data, unsigned char position)
{
sendLCDCommand(0xC0|position);    // Change the DDRAM address to second line by
//keeping Bit D7 high and setting address at 0x40 onwards
sendTextToLCD(data);
}


//write text to the LCD
void sendTextToLCD(unsigned char *data)
{
while (*data)
{
writeCharToLCD(*data);
data++;
}
}

// initialize LCD

void initializeLCD(void)
{
// Set the direction of port pins connected to LCD display as output ports
// We are permanently connecting R/W pin to ground. So there is no read instruction in this case
LCDDDR |= (1<<LCD_DB4)|(1<<LCD_DB5)|(1<<LCD_DB6)|(1<<LCD_DB7)|(1<<LCD_RS)|(1<<LCD_ENABLE_BIT);

//After reset, data sheet suggests some delay.
CL_delayMS(LCD_INIT_DELAY);


// Note some sites says three times 8 bit mode setting commands need to be sent.
// But it is observed that even without this, LCD works fine. So 1st Command, 2nd Command and 3rd Commands can be deleted below.
//ENABLE_LCD();
// 1st Command
SET_EIGHT_BIT_MODE();
sendLCDPulse();    // Do not delete this. Need to further analyze. If pulse if sent it is not working
//CL_delayMS(5);     // Do not use this delay since delay is not acurate, Either use _delay_ms or use timers
_delay_ms(5);


// Second Command
SET_EIGHT_BIT_MODE();
sendLCDPulse();
_delay_us(100);
//CL_delayuS(100);   // Do not use this delay since delay is not acurate, Either use _delay_ms or use timers

// third Command
SET_EIGHT_BIT_MODE();
sendLCDPulse();
//CL_delayuS(100);   // Do not use this delay since delay is not acurate, Either use _delay_ms or use timers
_delay_us(37);
// Finally Set four bit mode
SET_FOUR_BIT_MODE();
sendLCDPulse();
CL_delayuS(100);

// First time when 4 bit mode command is sent, only one higher nibble was sent since
// only 4 bits are connected from MPU to LCD. Since D0 to D3 of LCD are not connected,
// their values depend on how the pins are connected in LCD module (May be grounded, may kept open etc)
//So again send function set command to set 2 line display mode mode and 5x7 character mode. But now two write operations to LCD is made
// inside the function sendLCDCommand.
sendLCDCommand (FOUR_BIT_5_BY_10_2LINE);


//turn on display and cursor OFF, Blink OFF (sent two times using below command)
sendLCDCommand (CURSOR_OFF_BLINK_OFF);

//clr display
sendLCDCommand (CLEAR_DISPLAY);

// Set Entry mode left to right
sendLCDCommand (ENTRY_MODE_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

}

void displayNumberTest(int range)
{
float fNum = -0.332;
unsigned char lcdBuffer[50];
sendLCDCommand(CLEAR_DISPLAY);
//setRowAndColumnPositionOnDisplay (0,0);
//sendTextToLCD("Decimal = ");
for (int count=0;count<range;count++)
{

itoa(count,lcdBuffer,2);
setRowAndColumnPositionOnDisplay (1,0);
sendTextToLCD(lcdBuffer);
itoa(count,lcdBuffer,16);
setRowAndColumnPositionOnDisplay (1,13);
sendTextToLCD(lcdBuffer);
itoa(count,lcdBuffer,10);
setRowAndColumnPositionOnDisplay (0,0);  // 1st Row, 0th position
sendTextToLCD(lcdBuffer);

// Now display some floating value number.
// use the function dtostrf(). It take 4 parameters
// Parameter1: The value to be converted
// 2: Width
//3. Precision
// 4. String to hold ASCII

// It is also possible to  use sprintf function. But it takes more memory.

fNum=(fNum*(-1)*(count+1)/101.12)+0.012;
dtostrf(fNum,5,3,lcdBuffer);
setRowAndColumnPositionOnDisplay (0,7);
sendTextToLCD(lcdBuffer);
CL_delayMS(300);
}

}

// Scroll the display
// This program need to be modified further to display only whatever characters are there in DDRAM.
// Right now 4 columns will be shifted just to demonstrate.
void scrollingDisplayTest(unsigned char *row1Text, unsigned char* row2Text, unsigned int scrollDelay)
{
unsigned char count=40;
sendLCDCommand(CLEAR_DISPLAY);
displayInRow1(row1Text);
displayInRow2(row2Text);
CL_delayMS(2000);
while(count--)
{
sendLCDCommand(SHIFT_ENTIRE_LEFT);
CL_delayMS(scrollDelay);

}
}


void LCDDemoProgram(unsigned char *row1Data, unsigned char *row2Data)
{

initializeLCD();
sendTextToLCD (row1Data);
setRowAndColumnPositionOnDisplay (1,0);
sendTextToLCD (row2Data);
CL_delayMS(3000);
sendLCDCommand(CLEAR_DISPLAY);
// Just to demostrate how Hex values can be displayed without using itoa library function
displayOneByteHexValue(0,0,CLKPR);
setRowAndColumnPositionOnDisplay (1,0);
displayOneByteHexValue(1,12,0xE2);
CL_delayMS(3000);
sendLCDCommand(CLEAR_DISPLAY);
//Wait for 3 seconds
scrollingDisplayTest("Display will be cleared for 3 sec after displaying DONE ", "Please Wait.... Please Wait.....",1000);
CL_delayMS(2000);
sendLCDCommand(CLEAR_DISPLAY);
displayInRow1("DONE");
CL_delayMS(3000);
displayInRow1("Cur OFF Bl OFF");
sendLCDCommand(CURSOR_OFF_BLINK_OFF);
CL_delayMS(3000);
sendLCDCommand(CLEAR_DISPLAY);
displayInRow1("Cur OFF Bl ON");
sendLCDCommand(CURSOR_OFF_BLINK_ON);
CL_delayMS(3000);
sendLCDCommand(CLEAR_DISPLAY);
displayInRow1("Cur ON Bl OFF");
sendLCDCommand(CURSOR_ON_BLINK_OFF);
CL_delayMS(3000);
sendLCDCommand(CLEAR_DISPLAY);
displayInRow1("Cur ON Bl ON");
sendLCDCommand(CURSOR_ON_BLINK_ON);
CL_delayMS(3000);
displayNumberTest(100);


}


////////////////////////////////////////////////    Do No Use Below code. This is Only for demo purpose//////////////////////////////////////////

// Function to convert lower nibble to ASCII Value
//Only lower nibble of the input is considered and higher nibble is lost
// This function is written for understanding purpose only.
// itoa () library function can be used instead of this with base of 16.

unsigned char convertLowerNibbleToASCIIValue(unsigned char data)
{
data&=0x0F;
if(data<=9)
{
return(data+0x30);
}
else            // There is no chance for getting more than 0x0F in the lowerNibble Parameter)
{
return(data+0x37);
}
}

// Function to convert Higher nibble to ASCII Value
//Only higher nibble of the input is considered and lower nibble is lost
unsigned char convertHigherNibbleToASCIIValue(unsigned char data)
{
data>>=4;
if(data<=9)
{
return(data+0x30);
}
else            // There is no chance for getting more than 0x0F in the lowerNibble Parameter)
{
return(data+0x37);
}
}

void displayOneByteHexValue(unsigned char rowNum, unsigned char pos, char data)
{
char temp;
setRowAndColumnPositionOnDisplay(rowNum,pos);
temp = convertHigherNibbleToASCIIValue(data);
writeCharToLCD(temp);
temp = convertLowerNibbleToASCIIValue(data);
writeCharToLCD(temp);

}

// Displays 8 bit Register values in LCD display unit.
// name is the name of the register to be displayed. You can give any name.
// port is the register name.


void displayRegisterValues(unsigned char *displayName, volatile uint8_t *registerName)
{
char temp2;
displayInRow1(displayName);
//temp2=registerName;
temp2 = (convertLowerNibbleToASCIIValue(*registerName));
displayInRow1(&temp2);
// Get the higher Nibble
temp2 = (convertLowerNibbleToASCIIValue((*registerName)>>4));
displayInRow2(&temp2);

}


int main(void)
{
    LCDDemoProgram("Hello", "World is Great");
    while(1)
    {
        //TODO:: Please write your application code 
    }
    return(0);
}
```