# Issue with Null terminating string display

Tags: c, avr-gcc

I have written small piece of code for displaying data in 2x16 character LCD.

```
char str2[] = "Hello Welcome";
char *ptr2=str2;

initializeLCD();
sendLCDCommand(CLEAR_DISPLAY);
while(*ptr2) {
    displayInRow1(ptr2++);
    CL_delayMS(300);
}
```

In this code, the display displays "Hello Welcomeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"
I thought while(*ptr2) will terminate after printing last letter "e" in the string. If I comment the line containing while(*ptr2), the data is displayed correctly. I am not sure what is wrong with this code above.
I am using Atmel Studio with Atmega328 controller. displayInRow1() function is tested and no issue with that.

Comment: Your code looks fine. `while(*ptr2)` will terminate as soon as you reach `'\0'` in the string. Since you are not modifying the string, you could use `char *str2 = "Hello Welcome" ` to avoid copying the literal into writable memory.

Comment: Looks like you want `displayInRow1(*ptr2++);`, no?

Comment: The function prototype is void displayInRow1(char* data);  So I want to call displayInRow1(ptr2++).  I changed the string declaration as per your suggestion as char *str2 = "Hello Welcome";  But not sure why I see eeeeeeeeeeeeeee at the end.

Comment: No sane function printing a `char` would take a pointer. Are you sure that function does not already print a string? If not: check the function; that looks broken by design. Post the function. (Strange enough: how can you display >16 chars in one row of an LCD with only 16 chars width?)

Comment: My complete LCD code is in the link below. Refer to my last edit and not the first post.  In the above case, I am not displaying 16 characters. Even otherwise LCD would scroll and display in my above code since I am displaying every time from position 1. I am expecting this almost like a scrolling display. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221491/displaying-hexadecimal-value-in-lcd/31231450?noredirect=1#comment50488824_31231450

Comment: I did refer to what is the most current version. You should post a [mcve], which includes **correct** error output; that's what we have to rely on'. (Note: normally, such small display do **not** scroll (about the link: tl;dr!), that does the name of your output function actually imply). Apparently my comment was quite correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `displayInRow1()` takes a pointer and passes it to `sendTextToLCD()` which displays a string. That's why it works correctly when you remove the `while`. So all you need is

```
initializeLCD();
sendLCDCommand(CLEAR_DISPLAY);
displayInRow1(str2);
```

I am not going to try to explain the result you are getting, except to say the `while` loop displays something like this

```
Hello Welcome
ello Welcome
llo Welcome
lo Welcome
o Welcome
 Welcome
Welcome
elcome
lcome
come
ome
me
e
```

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful explanation. I was  also expecting exactly the same what you entered at the end. But I was seeing eeeeeeeee at the end in the display and got confused and I was thinking that loop is not coming out when it encounters '\0'. I could not initially make out why it is displaying it. Now I realize that the last e remains  in the display from the previous calls.